# gracefully terminating processes with killall <processname>

Tags: process, kill, signals, process-management

I am using several instances (profiles) of Icedove (Thunderbird) and when I need to close all of them, I use:

```
killall icedove
```

According to `man killall`, if no signal name is specified, `SIGTERM` is sent.

```
And, `SIGTERM` allows the process to perform nice termination releasing 
resources and saving state if appropriate.
```

When I closed Icedove after an Addon installation, the configuration changes that I have made to the addon were lost. I had to repeat the steps and close Icedove properly (using exit in Menu).

I understand that this is only anecdotal evidence. I don't have enough observation to make any conclusive claims.

But still, **is there any possibility to make the termination request even "nicer" than `killall <processname>`** , so that the termination is as clean as if the application was closed using menu->Exit?

Comment: Does `icedove` have a system-tray-mode, i.e. is there a menu item to `Close` (minimize to tray) besides `Exit/Quit` (which quits the app) ?

Comment: I am not aware of Icedove having system-tray-mode (minimize to tray)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SIGTERM *allows* a process to perform cleanup before it terminates, but whether or not the process actually does so, and what sort of cleanup it performs, depends on how the program was written and (to an extent) on the facilities that the language the program was written in provides. So when a program receives SIGTERM it's not obliged to save anything, but it's quite likely that any files that it currently has open will get closed.

There are "nicer" signals than SIGTERM, eg SIGUSR1, but a program will ignore such signals unless it's been written to specifically listen for them.

Comment: `SIGUSR1` can mean anything depending on the application. It's not necessarily related to terminating it.

Comment: @Leiaz: Agreed! I didn't mean to imply that SIGUSR1 was related to terminating processes, merely that it's a signal that a program _may_ listen to, and it _could_ be used as a more gentle "time to shut down" signal than those associated with SIGTERM and SIGKILL, if such a thing were required.

Comment: In this particular case Icedove *may* react better to SIGINT than SIGTERM, but that is just conjecture.

Comment: Good point, @CameronNemo, and definitely worth testing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `wmctrl` to gracefully close all windows of a particular application<sup>1</sup> (as far as I know it's *"as clean as if the application was closed using menu->Exit"*).
using app `wm_class`:

```
for win in $(wmctrl -lx | awk '$3 ~ /Icedove/ {print $1}'); do wmctrl -ic "$win"; done
```

using app `pid`:

```
for win in $(wmctrl -lp | awk -v icepid=$(pgrep icedove) '$3 == icepid {print $1}'); do wmctrl -ic "$win"; done
```

---

<sup>1: With a tray-enabled application, closing it will minimize it to the tray. If it’s already in the tray, then `-c` won’t do anything. `wmctrl` doesn’t have an alternate close or a ‘kill’ command for this case ([source](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/wmctrl/)).</sup>